# When to use sum v.s. lpSum using pulp?

Tags: pulp

In the case study "[A Set Partitioning Problem](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/CaseStudies/a_set_partitioning_problem.html#)" in the pulp documentation "sum" is used to express the constraints, for example:

```
#A guest must seated at one and only one table
for guest in guests:
    seating_model += sum([x[table] for table in possible_tables
                                if guest in table]) == 1, "Must_seat_%s"%guest
```

Whereas "lpSum" seems to be used otherwise. Consider for example the following constraint in the case study [A Transportation Problem](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/CaseStudies/a_transportation_problem.html)

```
for b in Bars:
    prob += lpSum([vars[w][b] for w in Warehouses])>=demand[b], "Sum_of_Products_into_Bar%s"%b
```

Why is "sum" used in the first example? And when to use "sum" v.s. "lpSum"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `lpSum` every time you have at least one pulp variable inside the sum expression. Using `sum` is not wrong, just more inefficient. We should probably change the docs so they are consistent. Feel free to open an issue or, even better, do a PR so we can correct the Set Partitioning Problem example.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I have made a PR here https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/pull/323. Note that this is my first PR, but I hope it is correct - tell me if not.