# PuLP code is very slow to compile the problem - any suggestions?

Tags: python, pulp

I find that this code block is very slow in problem compile time for **PuLP**. Is there a faster way to rewrite this?

```
for item in supplylist:
    cn_coal_problem += (supplyitembynode[item]+
                        lpSum([massflowtype[(i,j,ct)] for (i,j,ct) in flowslist if (j,ct) == item]) >=
                        lpSum([massflowtype[(i,j,ct)] for (i,j,ct) in flowslist if (i,ct) == item]))
```

This problem seems to take 9 hours to compile which is far from ideal or even workable. There are a number of blocks written like this so I need to work out how to rewrite something much more performant.

This could also be an issue of size...

```
massflowtot length:  41631
massflowtype length:  499572
supplyitembynode length:  149988
```

Edit: Changes made, still pretty slow:

```
    counter = len(supplylist)
for item in supplylist:
    counter-=1
    if counter%100 == 0:
      print(counter, datetime.now()-start_build)
    cn_coal_problem += supplyitembynode[item]+lpSum(massflowtype[(i,j,ct)] for (i,j,ct) in flowslist if (j,ct) == item) >=lpSum(massflowtype[(i,j,ct)] for (i,j,ct) in flowslist if (i,ct) == item)
```

Output as below:

```
Started building at  12:40:20
149900 0:00:19.364037
149800 0:00:35.527059
149700 0:00:51.487889
149600 0:01:06.100106
149500 0:01:21.067001
149400 0:01:36.128091
149300 0:01:50.552957
149200 0:02:04.867231
149100 0:02:19.259758
149000 0:02:33.862139
```

Answer (score 1):

If the below doesn't help tremendously, you should update your question with additional information....  What is the dimensionality of all components?

First, remove the unnecessary parens and list creation that you have.  You are making unnecessary lists inside of the sum.  The outer parens *might* be mistaken for a generator.  Also, replace `lpSum` with regular `sum` might help for large generators if you don't need the additional functionality of `lpSum`.

Like this:

```
for item in supplylist:
    cn_coal_problem += supplyitembynode[item]+
                        sum(massflowtype[(i,j,ct)] for (i,j,ct) in flowslist if (j,ct) == item) >=
                        sum(massflowtype[(i,j,ct)] for (i,j,ct) in flowslist if (i,ct) == item)
```

Then you might consider (separate from the constraint section) making a dictionary for looking up appropriate items in the `flowlist` indexed by item to accelerate that portion if you are doing it many times:

```
flowlist_by_item_i = { item_i : [(i, j, ct), ...] }
flowlist_by_item_j = { item_j : [(i, j, ct), ...] }
```

where `item_i` are (i, ct) tuples, etc.

EDIT:

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63081381/when-to-use-sum-v-s-lpsum-using-pulp), using `lpSum` *should* be faster.  I'd be curious what your results are both ways after you remove the parens and brackets...

Comment: massflowtot length:  41631
massflowtype length:  499572
supplyitembynode length:  149988

Comment: @nemo_incognito How many matches are you expecting/getting for your generator where you test for equality with an item?  1?  10?  10,000?  I'm asking to help deduce whether that generator might be accelerated as I mentioned above by using dictionaries, or whether the expression generation is slow because it has 1000's of LpVariables.

Comment: @nemo_incognito. OBTW, 500K variables is humongous.  You should probably look at strategies to reduce that

Comment: So some sense of size of the problem:massflowtot length:  41631
massflowtype length:  499572
supplyitembynode length:  149988
149988
flowslist type:  <class 'list'>
flowslist length:  499572

Comment: Got that part, but I was asking the expected size of the generated expression where you are matching the item.  Also, it seems that you have some flow problem between i, j nodes.  Edit your problem to describe that.  Is the graph fully connected or quite sparse and how are you handling that...

Comment: I think the optimization that uses 'flowlist_by_item_i' etc would be best so that you remove the if statement from your list expresions.
lpSum can also take a generator expression, so that may help especially if you are hitting memory constraints.
Add timing statements to see which constraints take the longest time to generate, and you can see what improvements any changes make.
Also I would create a smaller problem (that solves in less than a minute) so you can quickly iterate solutions,

Comment: Going to take a crack at this in JuMP but yes... it is humungous, but so is China's power grid / coal transport network / steel plants.

Comment: Well, you may be making a fundamental mistake if you aren't modeling the network with a **sparse** matrix.  You should **only** have entries in the matrix for connected (i, j) pairs, not all of them.  Unclear from limited context if you are doing that.  You might want to update your post with more details and a SMALL sample of your dataset to show how you are handling key design points